# PHP - if something is equal to something then echo something

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm quite new to PHP now that I've started working with wordpress.

I'm trying to get something to work by using 'if'

Essentialy what I'm wanting to do is

If the status is equal to Open then return `<a href="#" id="flashing">Link</a>`
If the status is not equal to Open then return `<a href="#">Link</a>`

Here's what I think would work:

```
<?php
   if ($status) == (open) {
     echo "id=flashing"
   }
?>
```

Obviosuly, I'm assuming this doesn't work but what I'm wanting to do is create a link

Any help?

Comment: What it is `(open)`? a string?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really basic PHP syntax question; please read some documentation, and look at some examples before asking for help with every piece of code you write.

There is [a comprehensive online manual for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), with many examples. It is available in multiple translations, in case English is not your first language.

Things you have wrong in your example, with links to relevant pages of the manual:

- no [semi-colon to end the statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)
- no [quotes around the string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) `open`
- brackets in the wrong place in [the if statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

The text of your question also confuses [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and [`echo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), which have very different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

**Does this help?**

```
if ($status == 'open') {
  echo '<a href="#" id="flashing">Link</a>';
} else {
  echo '<a href="#" >Link</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code:

```
<?php
    if ($status == 'Open') {
      echo '<a href="#" id="flashing">Link</a>';
    } 
    else {
      echo '<a href="#" >Link</a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($status == 'open') 
{
   echo '<a href="link" id="flashing">Link</a>';
}
else
{
   echo '<a href="link" >Link</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Open` is a string, it can be written like this (alternatively to the other answers):

```
echo '<a href="#" '.(($status == 'Open') ? 'id="flashing"':'').'>Link</a>';
```